# Build wp8 app using ionic

Tags: windows-phone-8, ionic-framework

I am creating a hybrid app using ionic framework.I have successfully created build for android and ios. But when I am creating app for wp8.I got error:

```
Building project: D:/window/platforms/wp8/window.sln
        Configuration : debug
        Platform      : any cpu
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
D:\window\platforms\wp8\window.csproj(211,5): error MSB4019: The imported projec
t "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.WindowsP
hone.v8.0.Overrides.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import
> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
ERROR: Error code 1 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild
 with args: D:/window/platforms/wp8/window.sln,/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyL
ist;Verbosity=minimal,/nologo,/p:Configuration=debug,/p:Platform=any cpu
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
```

Please help

Comment: the answer below is  good enough? If so, make it your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think WP8 is not supported, only Windows 10. Look here:

**"We will not be supporting WP8.
We may support W10 with V1, but we will definitely support W10 with V2."**

and

**For many, this is probably not the Windows Phone 8 update you were hoping for, but we just couldn’t get Ionic apps to perform well enough on that platform to officially support it. With all the changes and updates in the Windows/Edge ecosystem over the last few months, it made sense to just wait and see how it all played out.**

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/does-ionic-supports-windows-phone-8/29233/22

https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/One-Dev-Minute/Ionic-apps-on-Windows-10

http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-1-2/